# Почему нет запятой?

Tags: пунктуация

Почему в этом предложении перед "как" не стоит запятая: "Он как никто чувствует взаимосвязь событий во времени"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что это усечённая форма устойчивого выражения "как никто другой", поэтому запятые не ставятся. Устойчивые выражения с союзом как (и не только)не обособляются.